# Related to google adsense

Tags: redirect, adsense

i am very confused if someone know about it then please help.

Suppose i have a website "www.abc.cx.ee" (subdomain) ,when i tried to verify this website for using adsense, the adsense account gives me an error that "you should have a domain for example www.exmple.com not a subdomain..... thats ok.

After that i register for another domain "example.cf" and then redirect it to my original website "www.abc.cx.ee" and apply for google adsense with domain "example.cf". Google asked me to place the ad unit code on my website "example.cf".

SO HERE are my questions

Where do i suppose to place the ad unit code ? (i mean to say that i have registered for adsense on domain "example.cf" which will redirect to my original site "www.abc.cx.ee".

Will adsense work that way?
                                             ThankYou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The review process will start when you put ads **on** the URL you've submitted - and you can't redirect from it: nothing will happen on the AdSense side, and your application will be "pending" forever.

That means you *can* put ads and use AdSense on all your suitable-for-AdSense sites, but the initial (one-time) review process will start only when your primary URL start making the ad impressions.

If you can't change the URL and if you can't put ads on it, then you'll need to start another application with another Google account / email addres, if you want to submit another (valid and suitable for monetization) URL.

(And if you have any question specific to your application, account, site, you could ask experts on the official AdSense Help Forum - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/adsense)

Comment: one thing more if you can help with it , like i have a domain "example.cf" now where to get hosting so that i don't have to redirect to other website?